# Changing MacOSX environment variable to load glibtoolize

Tags: unix, libtool, bash

I am trying to set up a program which requires libtoolize on my mac.

When I installed libtool in terminal I got a message saying that libtool was already being used by Apple and so these programs had been installed as glibtool and glibtoolize. I then went into the autoconfig of the program I am trying to install and it had the helpful message saying:

> echo "Couldn't find a new-enough version of 'libtoolize', please install one!" 
>   echo "If you have a newer version, set the environment variable 'LIBTOOLIZE' to its path";

Since my problem is not that I have a newer version of this program, but rather that it has a different name, I was hoping that there was a way to redirect any requests for libtoolize to glibtoolize.  But because I am sadly only a beginner at UNIX I'm not sure how to do this.

I assume that I would have to use an if / fi statement in either the ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc files but that's as far as I could figure out on my own.

I apologize if this is a repeat question.

Comment: There seems to be a patch to do this [link](http://lists.rivendellaudio.org/pipermail/rivendell-prog/attachments/20090410/a8c51a29/attachment.bat) but I'm not entirely sure how to go about making this run.

Comment: Never mind.  Solved it myself.  Easy enough, just changed the autoconfig error check from libtoolz to glibtoolz and it went out and found the program itself.